# PHP-PDO: How would I wrap some values return into javascript to be rendered on a view?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I am new to MVC and I am trying to retrieve an array of image paths from mysql database, and build a grid via javascript with it.

The controller requires a model that makes a call to the database and returns all the paths.

Previously, I had an ajax call that opened up a poorly designed file that `echo json_encode()`.

Currently all files are being routed through the `index.php`. So would I just `echo json_code()` in the controller and have the ajax open `index.php`?

model/interest.php

```
class Interest
{
  private $cxn = Dd::getInstance();
  private $table = 'interestPix'

  function __construct(){}
  public function get_interest_pix()
  {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table";

    if ($stmt = $this->cxn->prepare($sql)) {
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

      $stmt = null;
      $this->$cxn = null;

      return $result;
    }
  }
```

controller/interest_controller.php

```
require_once 'models/interest.php';
/**
 *
 */
class InterestController
{

  function __construct(argument){}
  public function render_interest_pix()
  {
      $model = new Interest();
  }
}
```

ajax file:

```
function interest_grid() {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
           // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       } else {
           // code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             var jsonObj = xmlhttp.response;
             myFunc(jsonObj);
           }
       };
       xmlhttp.open("GET","views/interest_controller.php",true);
       xmlhttp.responseType = "json";
       xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, yes you would have the controller echo a json_encode of the result.  Be sure that's all that's is being echoed or you could get javascript errors when you parse the result.